# Linux Mint LAN Connecting But Not Working

Tags: networking, linux-mint, lan

I am using Linux Mint 17.2.

I am able to connect using LAN wire (i.e. on the right bottom it shows connected) but not able to access the internet. It works great on Wifi, but not working at all on LAN connection. I tried with the same LAN wire and same IP address on my friend's laptop (Windows), and it is working.

I have tried many things from [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet#TOC-No-wireless-connection-at-all), like installing a firmware package and driver, but no success.

UPDATE:
Ouptut of `ethtool eth0`:

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                   link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
    Link detected: yes
```

UPDATE #2: Ouptut of `ifconfig -a`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:4c:48:40  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e97:eff:fe4c:4840/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22396 errors:0 dropped:28 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1494318 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:45225 (45.2 KB)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13657 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13657 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1784044 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:1784044 (1.7 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:14:3d:ce:5d:cf  
          inet addr:10.1.7.159  Bcast:10.1.127.255  Mask:255.255.128.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c214:3dff:fece:5dcf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:238187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:319028848 (319.0 MB)  TX bytes:18195177 (18.1 MB)
```

Comment: How do you know your LAN is **connected** ? Just by looking at the link lights ? Also if you edit/update your post and include the output of `ethtool eth0` command (replace `eth0` with your ethernet adapter's name), people may have a clue what is happening.

Comment: @MelBurslan Updated the question. Yes, I see that the link is connected in lit on the bottom right. Also, it shows out of all connections, which one I am connected to.

Comment: another command output please `ifconfig -a`

Comment: @MelBurslan Updated. See the question. Please let me know even if you have a hunch. I am desperate.

Answer (score 0):

run this command

```
`ifconfig eth0 a.b.c.d netmask 255.255.255.0`
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the IP address you want to assign this interface and netmask value might change depending on your network architecture.

then run `ifconfig eth0 up`

Keep in mind, putting two network interfaces of a single server on the same subnet, is asking for trouble. So if your LAN IP address is going to be in the same range as your WLAN IP address, I strongly suggest **NOT** doing this. But it is your choice at the end. It might work for a while but intermittent problems may ensue, making troubleshooting next to impossible.